# Vuex Namespaced Store Sets Both States

Tags: vue.js, namespaces, vuex, store

In my project I have a rather complex vuex store which saves values of filter inputs and converts them into filters I can use to later query the backend. I use those filters next to two different tables. If I filter for id = 123 in table1 I DO NOT want to have the filter in table2 to be id = 123. Thats why I created a module and try to use a namespaced store. My vuex store index.js looks something like this:

```
import myFilterModule from './filter.module';
    Vue.use(Vuex);
    export default new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        filter1: myFilterModule,
        filter2: myFilterModule,
      },
    });
```

And my module looks like this:

```
const state = {
  idFilter: null,
};
const actions = {};
const mutations = {
  [SET_ID_FILTER](state, id) {
    state.idFilter = id;
  },
};
const getters = {
  getFilter(state) {
    return state.idFilter;
  },
};
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
};
```

The problem is, if I commit a change on either of those namespaces like this:

```
this.$store.commit('filter1/' + SET_ID_FILTER, '123');
```

Both of these functions:

```
this.$store.state['filter1'].idFilter
this.$store.state['filter2'].idFilter
```

Return the same. Even tho I didnt even set. idFilter on filter2.

Am I using the namespaces wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a state is the same object in both module copies. If a module is supposed to be reused, initial state should be created with factory function:

```
const state = () => ({
  idFilter: null,
});
...
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  ...
};
```

This is the reason why `state` is allowed to be a function.